# linux bash if statement inside for loop

Tags: bash, command-line

I am attempting to iterate through 1-30, say hello #number for each except for number 10. This is what I have which is not working

```
for i in {1..30}; do if [i != 10]; then echo "hello $i"; fi; done
```

my output from this is 
bash [i: command not found  -- thirty times

Comment: Just missing the spaces for [ and ]

Answer (score 19):

Your `if` statement is wrong, it should be `if [ $i != 10 ]`. Spaces around the `[` are mandatory, and your variables should have a `$` sign before it if you are reading them.

```
for i in {1..30}; do if [ $i != 10 ]; then echo "hello $i"; fi; done
```

Comment: I cannot choose your answer ... the only option I have is to choose the first reply as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

`if` tests commands.
`if [ ... ]` works because `[`  is a command (`/usr/bin/[` or a builtin (usually the latter)) that expects `]` as its last argument (just to make things look pretty). But other than that, it takes parameters, which needs to be passed as usual—as a space separated list.

If you don't want to use `[`, you can do:
`if test $i != 10; then` and it will behave exactly the same.

Alternatively, there's `[[` in *bash*, which is a proper grammar construct that creates a separate context, which allows you to use things like `>` or `&&` in it with semantics different from what they would mean in a usual command invocation (`[` and `test` are just command invocations), but you still need spaces around `[[` and `]]`.